# How to solve $\sin(x)=1/2$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$

Tags: trigonometry

Hej,
How to solve the function, $\sin(x)=1/2$, for $-\pi < x < \pi$.

Is it not just $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ and $\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$, or do we have to count from the other side??

Comment: The general solution is $x_1=\frac{\pi}{6}+2\pi k$ where $k \in Z$ and $x_2=\frac{5\pi}{6}+2\pi k$ where $k\in Z$. Now check which values lie in the given interval and you are done.

Comment: What is "the other side" and what do you think would happen if you counted "from" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution is

$$ \pi/6 + (-1)^k \pi $$

which gives $\pi/6, 5 \pi/6 $ plus all multiples of $2\pi...$ where we can count $k$ either clockwise or anticlockwise or both. The requirement is that the radius vector tip must be in that particular angular position.